# Encoding of tweets acquired through twitteR package

Tags: r, encoding, twitter

I don't know how to tell searchTwitter() function to encode tweets like UTF-8. I want "šćčđž" or "шђжћч" characters in the list. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you contacted the package maintainer?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at Tony Breyal's answer regarding RJSONIO and see if it helps:

[encoding issue using twitteR R package for Cyrillic tweets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995182/encoding-issue-using-twitter-r-package-for-cyrillic-tweets)