# encoding issue using twitteR R package for Cyrillic tweets

Tags: r, twitter, web

I want to parse Cyrillic tweets via twitteR package.

I run this simple code to get last 5 tweets:

```
> library("twitteR")
> tweets=userTimeline(user="ru_mts",n=100)
> tweets[1:5]
```

The output is below. What should I do to get it usable? There is definitely something with encoding. Thanks.

```
[[1]]
[1] "ru_mts: @potemkink \037@8 ?@52KH5=88 ;8<8B>2 B@0D8:0 459AB2CNB >3@0=8G5=8O A:>@>AB8. \025ABL CA;C38, =0 :>B>@KE ;8<8B 1>;LH5: http://t.co/EgbYhwfx. #\034\"!"

[[2]]
[1] "ru_mts: @step_42, C40;5=85 8=D-O > ?@52KH5=88 ;8<8B0 \021\030\" ?@>872>48BAO G5@57 *111*219# 2K7>2, 8;8 A<A A B5:AB>< stop =0 5340. \0215A?;0B=>. ^\030\020 #\034\"!"

[[3]]
[1] "ru_mts: @d_kosmos, 2 A;CG05 5A;8 C \0220A =5 ?>;CG05BAO 2>A?>;L7>20BLAO CA;C3>9 \03353:89 ?;0B56, @5:><5=4C5< 2>A?>;L7>20BLAO ?>765. ^\030\020 #\034\"!"

[[4]]
[1] "ru_mts: @d_kosmos, ?@54>AB02LB5 ?>60;C9AB0 \0220H \026B5; \034\"!, =8: 2 B28, =0 blogs@mts.ru \037@>25@8< 8=D>@<0F8N ?> B0@8DC, CA;C30< 8 1>=CA0<. ^\030\020 #\034\"!"

[[5]]
[1] "ru_mts: @katmirabo \034>6=> CB>G=8BL ?@8G8=C A?8A0=89 87 45B0;870F88 2 \030=B5@=5B-\037><>I=8:5: http://t.co/3ydhKfPL 8;8 ?>72>=82 ?> \0260890. ^\030\020 #\034\"!"
```

Here is the sessionInfo()

```
R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)

Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)


locale:

[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    
LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
other attached packages:
[1] Unicode_0.1-3  twitteR_0.99.9 RJSONIO_0.95-0 RCurl_1.6-10.1 bitops_1.0-4.1
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.14.0
```

Comment: It works for me. Mind reporting sessioInfo() so we have more info to work on?

Comment: thanks. i've added my session info

Comment: My version of twitteR is old, I tried updating but the package isn't buildig...

Comment: i was not able to install or build from source for R2.14 either. had to downgrade to R2.13 install twitteR, then uninstalled R2.13 keeping twitteR and finally installed R2.14. works fine excepts for encoding. guess it's a system issue, locales or smth.

Comment: Anyway, with `iconv()` you can change the encoding of char strings. Use `Encoding()` to see what encoding is using and change it UTF-8

Comment: wtf??? Package ‘twitteR’ was removed from the CRAN repository.

Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.

Comment: Sorry, the package is back on CRAN as of this week (the current version as of this moment 0.99.11 should be eschewed for the version I just uploaded, 0.99.12). It didn't pass check with R 2.14 and I just now was able to get to it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue actually resides with RJSONIO::fromJSON and RCurl::getURL which are/were striping out the 'UTF-8' encoding.

RJSONIO::fromJSON() didn't used to preserve the encoding but does if you update to RJSONIO 0.96-0.

Duncan is currently looking into the encoding issue for RCurl::getURL (it uses the correct encoding to create the character vector element but then something odd happens).

Short answer is to update RJSONIO to 0.96-0 and then update RCurl when the next version is released with a fix.

Comment: gosh RCurl was relatively recently published, on 2011-11-02. Any idea of when it might get updated? anyway thanks for pointing out where the problem is.

Comment: @dmitryungurean I reported this issue on 24 Oct. Duncan kindly replied saying that it's on his to-do list but given the number of packages he maintains, as well as his professional job, I think it's fair to say he's a very busy man, so no idea when he'll find time to resolve it.

Comment: Cool, looks like there's been some encoding enhancements (like you, I'll have to wait for a Windows binary to check them out): http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/Changes.html

Comment: strange. tried to build RCurl from source (it was my first attempt) but failed. though was able to build a package from this instruction on building R packages http://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~kbroman/Rintro/Rwinpack.html

Comment: installed RCurl 1.8-0.1 together with twitteR 0.99.14 unfortunately same encoding problem persists:(

Comment: Bugger. In that case you should send an email to the package maintainer of RCurl with a reproducible example and hopefully he might be able to troubleshoot further for you :(